# Error converting pyqt5 to exe: "Failed to execute script"

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, pyqt5, qmainwindow

Error converting pyqt5 to exe: After I convert code created by pyqt5 designer I got "Failed to execute script"

[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from imapclient import *


class TheWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TheWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setObjectName("Main_Window")
        self.resize(840, 600)

        self.setWindowTitle("Mail Cleaner")

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        # FRAME
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 821, 591))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")

        # #### EMAIL
        self.label_email = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_email.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 20, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_email.setFont(font)
        self.label_email.setObjectName("label_email")
        self.label_email.setText("E-Mail")

        self.lineedit_yourmail = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineedit_yourmail.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 271, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineedit_yourmail.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_yourmail.setObjectName("lineedit_yourmail")
        # self.lineedit_yourmail.setText("ahmedsayed551991@gmail.com")
        self.lineedit_yourmail.setPlaceholderText("Enter your email")

        # ### PASSWORD
        self.label_password = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 20, 101, 21))
        self.label_password.setFont(font)
        self.label_password.setObjectName("label_password")
        self.label_password.setText("Password")

        self.lineedit_password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineedit_password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 40, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineedit_password.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_password.setObjectName("lineedit_password")
        # self.lineedit_password.setText("ahmed01273290218")
        self.lineedit_password.setPlaceholderText("Enter your mail password")
        self.lineedit_password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)

        # TEXT BROWSER
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.frame)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(55, 201, 561, 221))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.textBrowser.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser.setHtml("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
            "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
            "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
            "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Times New Roman\'; font-size:11pt; font-weight:600; font-style:normal;\">\n"
            "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>")

        # PROGRESS BAR
        self.progressbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.frame)
        self.progressbar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 490, 561, 23))
        self.progressbar.setMinimum(1)
        self.progressbar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressbar.setObjectName("progressbar")

        self.button_login = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.button_login.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 40, 61, 31))
        self.button_login.setObjectName("button_login")
        self.button_login.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.button_login.setText("Login")

        self.button_delete = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.button_delete.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 430, 141, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(2)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.button_delete.setFont(font)
        self.button_delete.setObjectName("button_delete")
        self.button_delete.clicked.connect(self.delete_messages)
        self.button_delete.setDisabled(True)
        self.button_delete.setText("Delete")

        self.button_exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.button_exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 540, 101, 31))
        self.button_exit.setObjectName("button_exit")
        self.button_exit.clicked.connect(self.close_app_exit)
        self.button_exit.setText("EXIT")

        self.button_addmail = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.button_addmail.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 120, 101, 31))
        self.button_addmail.setObjectName("button_addmail")
        self.button_addmail.clicked.connect(self.add_mail)
        self.button_addmail.setDisabled(True)
        self.button_addmail.setText("Add mail to list")

        self.button_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.button_clear.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 440, 101, 31))
        self.button_clear.setObjectName("button_clear")
        self.button_clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_text_browser)
        self.button_clear.setText("Clear List")

        self.lineedit_mailer = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineedit_mailer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 441, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineedit_mailer.setFont(font)
        self.lineedit_mailer.setObjectName("lineedit_mailer")

        # self.lineedit_mailer.setText("noreply@medium.com")
        self.lineedit_mailer.setPlaceholderText("Enter email you wish delete it's messages")
        self.lineedit_mailer.setDisabled(True)

        self.label_mailer = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_mailer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 85, 91, 31))
        self.label_mailer.setFont(font)
        self.label_mailer.setObjectName("label_mailer")
        self.label_mailer.setText("E-mail From")

        self.label_emailslistname = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_emailslistname.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 170, 171, 31))
        self.label_emailslistname.setFont(font)
        self.label_emailslistname.setObjectName("label_emailslistname")
        self.label_emailslistname.setText("Emails You will delete")

        self.label_progress = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_progress.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 460, 71, 21))
        self.label_progress.setFont(font)
        self.label_progress.setObjectName("label_progress")
        self.label_progress.setText("Progress")

        self.label_mailinfo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_mailinfo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 200, 141, 221))
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        self.label_mailinfo.setFont(font)
        self.label_mailinfo.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_mailinfo.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label_mailinfo.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_mailinfo.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label_mailinfo.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_mailinfo.setObjectName("label_mailinfo")
        self.label_mailinfo.setText("information about activate mail")

        self.label_emailconfirmed = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_emailconfirmed.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 40, 121, 31))
        self.label_emailconfirmed.setFont(font)
        self.label_emailconfirmed.setObjectName("label_emailconfirmed")
        self.label_emailconfirmed.setText("Please Login")

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.frame)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 120, 71, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("English")

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

        self.deleted_mails = []

    # ============================================= FUNCTIONS =================================================
    imaplib._MAXLINE = 1000000

    def auto_detect_mail(self):
        # auto detect mail type (yahoo, Gmail, hotmail)
        if '@yahoo.com' in self.lineedit_yourmail.text():
            # print("auto_detect_mail(self): yahoo mail")
            return 'yahoo'

        elif '@gmail.com' in self.lineedit_yourmail.text():
            # print("auto_detect_mail(self): Gmail")
            return 'gmail'

        elif '@hotmail.com' in self.lineedit_yourmail.text():
            # print("auto_detect_mail(self): hotmail")
            return "hotmail"
        else:
            return False

    def internet_connection(self):
        # check internet connection
        url = 'http://www.google.com/'
        timeout = 5

        try:
            requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
            return True

        except requests.ConnectionError:
            self.label_emailconfirmed.setText("No internet")
            return False

    def login(self):
        try:
            self.lineedit_mailer.setDisabled(True)
            self.button_addmail.setDisabled(True)
            self.button_delete.setDisabled(True)

            # login email using address and password
            # yahoo mail
            if self.internet_connection() and self.auto_detect_mail() == 'yahoo':
                self.label_mailinfo.setText("please unprotect your email goto link yahoo imap activate")
                self.yahoo_e_mail = self.lineedit_yourmail.text()
                self.yahoo_password = self.lineedit_password.text()
                self.yahoo_imap_Object = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.mail.yahoo.com', ssl=True, port="993")
                self.yahoo_imap_Object.login(self.yahoo_e_mail, self.yahoo_password)
                self.label_emailconfirmed.setText("yahoo connected")
                # print("you have internet connection and yahoo register")

                self.lineedit_mailer.setDisabled(False)
                self.button_addmail.setDisabled(False)
                self.button_delete.setDisabled(False)
                return True

            # Gmail
            elif self.internet_connection() and self.auto_detect_mail() == 'gmail':
                self.label_mailinfo.setText("please unprotect your email goto link gmail imap activate")
                self.gmail_e_mail = self.lineedit_yourmail.text()
                self.gmail_password = self.lineedit_password.text()
                self.gmail_imap_Object = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', ssl=True)
                self.gmail_imap_Object.login(self.gmail_e_mail, self.gmail_password)
                self.label_emailconfirmed.setText("Gmail connected")
                # print("you have internet connection and 'gmail' register")

                self.lineedit_mailer.setDisabled(False)
                self.button_addmail.setDisabled(False)
                self.button_delete.setDisabled(False)
                return True

            # Hotmail
            elif self.internet_connection() and self.auto_detect_mail() == 'hotmail':
                self.label_mailinfo.setText("please unprotect your email goto link hotmail imap activate")
                self.hotmail = self.lineedit_yourmail.text()
                self.hotmail_password = self.lineedit_password.text()

                Server_name = "outlook.office365.com"
                self.hotmail_imap_Object = imapclient.IMAPClient(Server_name, ssl=True, port=993)
                self.hotmail_imap_Object.login(self.hotmail, self.hotmail_password)
                self.label_emailconfirmed.setText("hotmail connected")
                # print("you have internet connection and hotmail register")

                self.lineedit_mailer.setDisabled(False)
                self.button_addmail.setDisabled(False)
                self.button_delete.setDisabled(False)
                return True

            else:
                if self.internet_connection():
                    # print("Unknown email Or wrong email")
                    return False

        except:
            self.label_mailinfo.setText("Wrong mail or password")
            self.label_emailconfirmed.setText("Error")
            # print("Unknown email")

    def add_mail(self):  # so complicated
        # check if the mail have record messages if it haven't don't add

        # take the all messages from sender and store it in dictionary {key(sender): value(count)}.
        if self.lineedit_mailer.text() not in self.deleted_mails and "@" in self.lineedit_mailer.text():
            self.deleted_mails.append(self.lineedit_mailer.text())
            self.lineedit_mailer.clear()
        else:
            self.label_mailinfo.setText("Repeated Mail or wrong mailer")
            return False
        try:
            # login email using address and password
            # yahoo mail
            if self.internet_connection():

                if self.auto_detect_mail() == 'yahoo':
                    self.yahoo_imap_Object.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=False)
                    for link in self.deleted_mails:
                        search_address = f"FROM {link}"
                        self.yahoo_UIDs = self.yahoo_imap_Object.search(search_address)
                        # print(self.yahoo_UIDs)
                        for i in self.yahoo_UIDs:
                            self.content = f"FROM: {self.deleted_mails[-1]},  MESSAGES = {len(self.yahoo_UIDs)}"
                            # print(self.content)

                    self.textBrowser.append(str(self.content))

                # Gmail
                elif self.auto_detect_mail() == 'gmail':    # CONFIRMED FUNCTION
                    self.gmail_imap_Object.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=False)
                    for link in self.deleted_mails:
                        search = "FROM {}".format(link)
                        self.gmail_UIDs = self.gmail_imap_Object.search(search)
                        for i in self.gmail_UIDs:
                            self.content = f"FROM: {self.deleted_mails[-1]},  MESSAGES = {len(self.gmail_UIDs)}"

                    self.textBrowser.append(str(self.content))

                # Hotmail
                elif self.auto_detect_mail() == 'hotmail':

                    self.hotmail_imap_Object.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=False)
                    for link in self.deleted_mails:
                        search = "FROM {}".format(link)
                        self.hotmail_UIDs = self.hotmail_imap_Object.search(search)
                        # print(self.hotmail_UIDs)

                        for i in self.hotmail_UIDs:
                            self.content = f"FROM: {self.deleted_mails[-1]},  MESSAGES = {len(self.hotmail_UIDs)}"

                    # print(self.deleted_mails)
                    self.textBrowser.append(str(self.content))

                else:
                    if self.internet_connection():
                        self.label_mailinfo.setText("Write Valid Mail")
                        # print("Unknown email Or wrong email")

        except:
            # self.label_mailinfo.setText("please select\nyour email type")
            self.label_emailconfirmed.setText("choose mail")
            # print("Unknown email")
            return False

    def delete_messages(self):  # take mails in the list and delete it if it isn't empty
        # connect progressbar to delete messages and delete all messages stored in textBrowser
        if len(self.deleted_mails) > 0:
            if self.auto_detect_mail() == 'gmail':
                for link in self.deleted_mails:
                    from_search = "FROM {}".format(link)
                    self.after_gmail_UIDs = self.gmail_imap_Object.search(from_search)
                    for i in self.after_gmail_UIDs:
                        self.gmail_imap_Object.delete_messages(i)
                self.label_mailinfo.setText("Process Finished")
                return True

            elif self.auto_detect_mail() == 'yahoo':
                for link in self.deleted_mails:
                    from_search = "FROM {}".format(link)
                    self.after_yahoo_UIDs = self.yahoo_imap_Object.search(from_search)
                    for i in self.after_yahoo_UIDs:
                        self.yahoo_imap_Object.delete_messages(i)
                self.label_mailinfo.setText("Process Finished")
                return True

            elif self.auto_detect_mail() == 'hotmail':
                for link in self.deleted_mails:
                    from_search = "FROM {}".format(link)
                    self.after_hotmail_UIDs = self.hotmail_imap_Object.search(from_search)
                    for i in self.after_hotmail_UIDs:
                        self.hotmail_imap_Object.delete_messages(i)
                self.label_mailinfo.setText("Process Finished")
                return True

        else:
            # NOTHING TO DELETE
            return False

    def clear_text_browser(self):
        self.deleted_mails.clear()
        # print("self.deleted_mails.clear()")
        self.textBrowser.clear()
        # print("self.textBrowser.clear()")

    def close_app_exit(self):
        # try to logout Before EXIT
        try:
            if self.login():
                if self.auto_detect_mail() == 'yahoo':
                    self.yahoo_imap_Object.logout()
                    # print("self.yahoo_imap_Object.logout()")

                elif self.auto_detect_mail() == 'hotmail':
                    self.hotmail_imap_Object.logout()
                    # print("self.hotmail_imap_Object.logout()")

                elif self.auto_detect_mail() == 'gmail':
                    self.gmail_imap_Object.logout()
                    # print("self.gmail_imap_Object.logout()")
            else:
                self.label_emailconfirmed.setText("First login")
                # self.button_exit.clicked.connect(sys.exit(0))

                # print("no internet to logout")
        except:
            self.button_exit.clicked.connect(sys.exit(0))
            # print("exit except")
            # return False
        # EXIT
        self.button_exit.clicked.connect(sys.exit(0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = TheWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what did you use to convert your code to exe?

Comment: auto-py-to-exe or pyinstaller , i know they are the same and both not working

Comment: https://github.com/MrAhmedElsayed/Mail-remover/blob/master/new_edit.py

Comment: poste the full command you used to convert to .exe with pyinstaller

Comment: thank you, problem solved when i run the command in virtual environment the program run perfectly

Answer (score 0):

thank you, problem solved when i run the command in virtual environment the program run perfectly